# why pxssh.before behaves different when used with py.test.?

Tags: pexpect, pxssh

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
import time
import sys
s=pxssh.pxssh()

class Testinstall:

    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.s=pxssh.pxssh()
        cls.s.login('10.10.62.253', 'User','PW',auto_prompt_reset=False)

    def teardown_class(cls):
        cls.s.logout()

    def test_cleanup(cls):
        cls.s.sendline('cat test.py')
        cls.s.prompt(timeout=10)
        cls.s.sendline('cat profiles.conf')
        cls.s.prompt(timeout=10)
        print('s.before')
        print (cls.s.before)
        print('s.after')
        print(cls.s.after)
```

In above code `print(cls.s.before)` prints, output of both `cat` commands.
As per expectation it should only print output of the 2nd `cat` command i.e `cat profiles.conf`.
When tried in python session in shell it shows output of only second `cat` command ( as per expectation)

Comment: Does my answer explains your problem?

Comment: Oh Yes, It does. The first answer was a perfect solution. In the case of the second, the question itself was confusing. I jus want to ask if 'auto_prompt_reset =True' and  now PROMPT=x , somewhere in code you do s.PROMPT= y  then how to reset  PROMPT to x again.

Comment: If you don't get this question then you please can explain how to use 'sync_original_prompt ' API in pxssh.   Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can change `s.PROMPT` to other values at any time. It's just a variable which `.prompt()` would use.

Comment: I never tried `sync_original_prompt()`. Based on my understanding it would try its best to figure out your shell prompt and set `.PROMPT` accordingly.

Comment: Please consider accepting the asnwer if it helps. And you better ask new questions for other things as it's not easy to talk in the comments. :)

Comment: Thanks, It does help.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `auto_prompt_reset=False` for `pxssh.login()` then you cannot use `pxssh.prompt()`. According to the doc:

> `pxssh` uses a unique prompt in the `prompt()` method. If the original prompt is not reset then this will disable the `prompt()` method unless you manually set the `PROMPT` attribute.

So for your code, both `prompt()` would time out and `.before` would have all output and `.after` would be `pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT`.

---

The doc also says that

> Calling prompt() will erase the contents of the before attribute even if no prompt is ever matched.

but this is NOT true based on my testing:

```
>>> from pexpect import pxssh
>>> ssh = pxssh.pxssh()
>>> ssh.login('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'passwd')
True
>>> ssh.PROMPT = 'not-the-real-prompt'
>>> ssh.sendline('hello')
6
>>> ssh.prompt(timeout=1)
False
>>> ssh.before
'hello\r\n-bash: hello: command not found\r\n[PEXPECT]# '
>>> ssh.after
<class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
>>> ssh.sendline('world')
6
>>> ssh.prompt(timeout=1)
False
>>> ssh.before
'hello\r\n-bash: hello: command not found\r\n[PEXPECT]# world\r\n-bash: world: command not found\r\n[PEXPECT]# '
>>> ssh.after
<class 'pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT'>
>>>
```

From the result you can see `.before` is not erased for the 2nd `prompt()`. Instead it's appended with the new output.

Comment: Thank a lot for your quick reply. Can you help me with following ?, how to toggle between two different prompts? One being the default, which you get just after login, and other of BTEQ session,e.g 'BTEQ -- Enter your SQL request or BTEQ command:'. One expects other prompt after bteq login command.

Comment: Not quite understand what you mean by *toggle different prompts*. You don't need to change the prompt for multiple times. Just set your favorite prompt and stick with it or just use the default one that pxssh sets for you. For other purposes just call `expect()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh.sync_original_prompt() instead of ssh.prompt().